# Is every pseudorandom generator a one way function?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, one-way-function

$$G:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow\{0,1\}^{n+1}$$

If above function is a pseudorandom generator then is the same $G$ a one way function. I tried to prove this but failed a lot of time. Would be helpful if someone could provide some insight on this.

Comment: In the unlikely case [Yehuda Lindell’s answer](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/41145/12164) wasn’t already an eye-opener for you, you could additionally check some related Q&As like – for example – “[How can I prove/disprove that a construction yields a secure PRG?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/11321/12164)”

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Prove by contradiction. Assume that it is *not* a one-way function and that it can be inverted with non-negligible probability. Use this to construct a distinguisher that can distinguish truly random from $G(s)$ with non-negligible advantage. I leave the rest to you...