# why can't use only one way function to construct a PRG, and don't use the hard core predicate?

Tags: pseudo-random-generator, one-way-function

The one-way function can expose some of the input and stay one-way, but still, that doesn't give the input.

- As I read, we can't just construct a PRG from a OWF, but we need to use the hard core predicate of the OWF. Why is that?
- Assuming $|f(s)| > |s|$, why is constructing a PRG in the following way wrong? $G(s) = f(s)$
- Suppose $f$ is a permutation function. If $f$ gets a random $x$, then is $f(x)$ also random?

Comment: If you have three questions, ask three questions.

Comment: @fkraiem the three questions are very related , and helps the reader to get the whole idea of the title question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - As I read, we can't just construct a PRG from a OWF, but we need to use the hard core predicate of the OWF. Why is that?
> - Assuming |f(s)|>|s|, why is constructing a PRG in the following way wrong? G(s)=f(s)

**This depends what your OWF is!** For *some* OWFs, $G(s) = f(s)$ is a PRG; for some others it is not. If we want to be able to take *any* OWF and construct a PRG from it, then yes one possibility is to use a HCP for it.

Comment: but now do we know any candidate for one way function that could satisfy G(s) = f(s) when G is a PRG? or is it just that there maybe one and we still don't know about?

Comment: @odai You need to understand that a PRG is a function, and indeed it is an OWF. So, when you write $G(s) = f(s)$ it means that $f$ and $G$ are *the same thing*. In other words, *$f$ is a PRG*.

Answer (score 5):

The first one is really simple, you already said it yourself:

> as i read , we can't just construct a PRG from just OWF , but we need to use the hard core predicate of the OWF, why is that?

I guess you're familiar with the formal statements, but informally speaking we have:

- A function $f:\{0,1\}^* \rightarrow \{0,1\}^*$ is one-way, if we give the adversary $y = f(x)$ and the length $|x|$, and he has a negligible probability of finding $x'$, s.t. $f(x') = y$.
- a PRG is a function $g:\{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^m$, where the output is indisinguishable from $U^m$, denoting the uniform distribution over $m$ bits, and $m > n$

Now consider the following construction: $f'(x) = f(x)|1$, with $f$ being a OWF. Just concatenating a $1$ doesn't change much w.r.t. the security property of an OWF. And in fact, any adversary able to break $f(x)$ can easily be turned into an adversary for $f'(x)$ and vice versa. So $f'$ is a OWF iff $f$ is a OWF.

But it is quite obvious, that $f'$ is not a PRG, because the output of $f'$ can easily be distinguished from a uniform distribution, by just looking at the lowest ordered bit (always $1$ vs uniform).

But as you stated yourself: With a hardcore predicate, you can get a length extension. Maybe [these lecture notes](http://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/gb.pdf) make it more clear how to achieve that (and why it's necessary). Informally speaking: A OWF does not need to be impossible to invert for all parts of its output - while a PRG needs to be indistinguishable from randomness over all its output.

> why constructing prg in the following way is wrong G(s) = f(s) assuming |f(s)| > |s|?

If we specify $f(x):\{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ a length preserving OWF, and use the construction above, we get $f':\{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{n+1}$, which is also a OWF. This fulfills the length criteria of a PRG, but it is distinguishable. Being a OWF is not sufficient to be a PRG.

> f is a permutation function , if f gets a random x then is f(x) also random?

A [permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) is a bijection from a set, e.g. $\{0,1\}^n$ into itself. This means, there are no collisions and every element has a single preimage. Thus, if we consider an input drawn uniformly at random from $\{0,1\}^n$, then the output is also uniformly distributed over $\{0,1\}^n$ - because the permutation has a 1-to-1 relationship between inputs and outputs. But that is also fullfilled for example by $p(x) = x + 1 \mod n$ over $\mathbb{Z}_n$, and I don't think that's what you meant. But this is entirely unrelated to the concept of one-way functions and PRGs.

Comment: so if F is OWF then G(s) = F(s) is not pseudorandom , but could be an F that satisfy this ?i think  it could be  right (maybe one we dont know about) ?
 - from the known one way functions , are you familiar with a distinguisher for one them ?

Comment: This question is answered [here](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/41140/is-every-pseudorandom-generator-a-one-way-function). If you assume an adversary able to break the one-way property, then you can build a distinguisher: If there is no valid preimage (at least half of all values don't have one), you know it was random. That is better than guessing already for a non-negligible part of the challenges. By contraposition, a PRG is a OWF.

Comment: state my question in a different way : is there a distinguisher for the discrete logarithm problem? or any other known OWF(if they exist)? but without the manipulation like adding an addition bit in the end .

Comment: i think a permutation one way function $f: {0,1}^n \rightarrow {0,1}^n$  gets a random string , can't be distinguished , but other OWF maybe they could be distinguished (like the one you proposed in your answer).

Comment: Those are entirely new questions, so you should put them in new questions. And if you mean a [pseudorandom permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_permutation), you should write that... But then again, this question wouldn't make much sense, and also would be entirely unrelated to the others.

Answer (score -3):

> the OWF can expose some of the input and stay OWF

Not really, no. Parts of the input in the output lead to a non-negligible change of guessing the whole input.

> as i read , we can't just construct a PRG from just OWF , but we need
>   to use the hard core predicate of the OWF, why is that?

I guess you're referring to `G: n->n+1, G(x) = f(x)b(x)` , ie. G gets a true random value with n bit, calculates OWF f(x) which has n bit too, and adds one bit b(x) with b being a HPC of f.

If we remove `b(x)`, a bit is missing, so G transforms a true random value (x) with n bit to another value with n bit. Meaning, G is no pseudo-random *generator*, it generates nothing and is not better than using x directly.

If we modify `f` to output more bit than `x` has, it's not really pseudo-random anymore. Extreme example: x has 1 bit, ie. a true random stream of 0/1, and `f(x)` has 100 bit. The problem is, whatever 100bit-values `f(0)` and `f(1)` are, they are always the same two values. G can now generate endless pseudorandom occurances of two fixed 100bit values, instead of an endless stream of 200 pseudorandom single bits.

And how does a HCP as added bit helps?
`b(x)` is easy to calculate from x, that's trivial.
If `b` were not to be a HPC, it's also easy to calculate from `f(x)`, and that means it doesn't add something (pseudo)random to the output. The output should contain something looking random, not something that can be calculated from previous output bits.
So, `b` is a HCP, meaning it can be calculated form x (of course), but not from `f(x)`.

> why constructing prg in the following way is wrong G(s) = f(s)
>   assuming |f(s)| > |s|?

See above.

Comment: first:
 there is an OWF that expose some of the input and still irreversible  , ( e.g let g  OWF , then we construct f($x_1,x_2$)=(g($x_1$),$x_2$) , g is an OWF ).
second:
"If we modify f to output more bit than x has, it's not really pseudo-random anymore." sorry but that doesn't make any sense .
third :
i understand why B(x) helps , the question is why can't we just use f.

Comment: @odai About (g(x1),x2) : Well, in this case, g is irreversible, but (g(x1),x2) not. The exposed input is not x1, but x2, and x2 is reversible. A oneway function is defined as function where the reversion can be done only with a negligible chance of success, and if you look up the definition of that, you'll see it doesn't hold. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function

Comment: About `"If we modify f to output more bit than x has, it's not really pseudo-random anymore."`: Did you read the next sentences, or the `...can easily be distinguished from a uniform distribution...` in the other answer? If my function transforms 1 to 111 and 0 to 000, inputting a true random stream of 1/0, eg. 1101, will give me 111111000111. As you can see, always triples. If I  know the first byte of a triple, I know the next two too.

Comment: About ` i understand why B(x) helps , the question is why can't we just use f.`: Again, read the answer, that you apparently don't understand at all. I just told you in the previous comment why the output of f can't be longer than the input, and if they have the same length, the pseudorandom generator doesn't generate new data. If I want random data of the same length, I don't need the generator atall, I can use the random input.

Comment: This is a well known proven argument , and not a discussable argument, you can prove it by reduction...

Comment: @odai What exactly is a well-proven argument?

Comment: Let f be an OWF then g(x1x2)= (f(x1),x2) is an OWF, when |x1| =|x2|

Comment: @odai Well, `|x1| =|x2|` was missing until now... (and yes, it makes a difference)

Comment: Yes ofcourse , it makes a difference, i assumed it since its well known.

Comment: @odai What does it matter if this statement is well known? In the answer, I just said that the statement in your question (without `|x1| =|x2|`) is false. ... Anyways, I'm now done discussing this, I've still much to do.

Comment: Actually $|x_1|= |x_2|$ is not needed. $|x_1|$ just has to be non-negligible (w.r.t. the total length). But almost all of the arguments here (both in the post and the discussion) are wrong or imprecise.

Comment: @tylo I'd be glad if I hear a single one.

Comment: @deviantfan "Not really, no. Parts of the input in the output lead to a non-negligible change of guessing the whole input. " W.r.t. OWFs, this is wrong already, as pointed out several times. "If we remove b(x), a bit is missing, so G transforms a true random value (x) with n bit to another value with n bit" A hardcore bit is not truely random - it can't be distinguished from a truely random bit. And that whole statement is questionable at best. Looking at the next sentence, a PRG is not defined as generating additional entropy, it is about being indistinguishable from a uniform distribution.

Comment: `a PRG is not defined as generating additional entropy, it is about being indistinguishable from a uniform distribution` With a truly random input and just that requirement, even `G(x)=x` would be PRG. ... Maybe I just don't understand you, but such a definition is hard to believe. `A hardcore bit is not truely random` In the previously quoted sentence, I never said hardcore bits are truly random - the input x is (`... G transforms a true random value (x) with n bit to...`) ...

Comment: And about the first sentence, I was several times told that my answer to a statement is wrong *after altering that statement* (either |x1|=|x2| and/or |x1| being non-negligible) ... Anyways, apparently I'm too stupid to see why I'm wrong, or my English is so bad that my sentences can't be understood, whatever.